# IDE does not suggest methods available on the selected object

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

I am very new to Python world. Pardon for any inane mistake(s).

**What program is trying to do?**
I just wrote a piece of code which reads the data from an existing excel and printing a selected cell value.

**Problem?**
Problem is IDE is not showing all the suggestion like when control loaded the sheet (of type Worksheet) the object name "sheet" does not show methods available in sheet object.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

test_f_path = '/Users/new_python_user/_Codes/_Personal/test_resources/Test_Update.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Eight'

workbook = load_workbook(test_f_path)
sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
print(sheet.cell(1, 1).value)   # <--- Here is problem: typing "sheet." does not provide suggestions
```

**Pycharm Version**
Pycharm Community 2019.3.3 for MAC

**EDIT-1** 
Modified the program to cast the object then it worked. But this is not the way i thought about Python. May be i am missing something. Pls advice.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet # <--Imported here

test_f_path = '/Users/i852841/_Codes/_Personal/PyStockCrawler/test_resources/Test_Update.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Eight'

workbook = load_workbook(test_f_path)
sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
sheet_casted = Worksheet(sheet) #<-- Cast here
```

Comment: This is for PyCharm right? I'm assuming so based on the tag. What version of PyCharm are you using?

Comment: Pycharm Community 2019.3.3

Comment: @Phillyclause89 is there any problem with my import?

Comment: I really don't know if `from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet` will have unforeseen consequences or not, but it does appear to fix the issue of Pycharm not showing the code suggestions for that object. I guess you'll have to test it and find out.

Comment: Thank you @Phillyclause89 for the time.. The suggestion problem, even its happening with other libs like DataFrame etc. I am exploring if something wrong with the environment configured with PyCharm

Comment: This is weird that is happening for you with `pandas.DataFrame`, I usually get the all the `pandas` functions and methods in the code suggestions. Though maybe this was just an issue with `openpyxl`.

Comment: My bad.. its all good with pandas and DataFrame. Its just having problem with openpyxl

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/auto-completing-code.html this might or might not be helpful to you.

Comment: Will take a look.. Thank you @Phillyclause89